# Angle of circumscribed arc

Tags: geometry

If I have 3 3D points:

- A $\{x_A;y_A;z_A\}$
- B $\{x_B;y_B;z_B\}$
- C $\{x_C;y_C;z_C\}$

[image]

There is a formula to calculate the angle of the circumscribed arc?

[image]

Knowing that:

- A is always the start point
- B is always the end point
- C is always an intermediate point

---

## Edit

Seeking for a simpler way, I remark this relation:

[image]

Knowing that:

- $0° \lt \alpha \lt 180°$

We can observe:

- $\gamma = 2\alpha$
- $\beta = 2\pi-\gamma = 2\pi-2\alpha = 2(\pi-\alpha)$

So it remains for me to calculate $\alpha$ angle with 3D vectors.

Is that this relationship is valid?

Comment: We can compute from $sin\alpha=\frac{a×b}{ab}$.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. I'm not going to write down the formula, because it'll involve a possible divide-by-zero. But I'll give an algorithm (with error-cases) for doing what you want.

1. Compute $M = (A + C)/2$; $N = (A + B)/2$, $v = C - A$, $w = B - A$. If either $v$ or $w$ is zero, it's an error.
2. The perpendicular bisectors of $AC$ and $AB$ are given by 
   $$
   (X-M) \cdot v = 0\\
   (X-N) \cdot w = 0
   $$
   Solve** these simultaneous equations to find the circle center, which I'll call $Q$ rather than $O$. If the equations have no single solution, then the points $A-B-C$ are collinear, and there is no circle containing the three of them, and it's an error.
3. Let $u = B - Q$, and $w = u^{\perp}$ (see below). Let $c = (A-Q) \cdot u$ and $s = (A-Q) \cdot w$. The angle is then atan2(c, s).

Details:
When I write $(A+C)/2$, I mean that you are to do coordinate-wise additiona nd division by two, i.e., 
$$
((a_x + c_x)/2, (a_y + c_y)/2)
$$
I mean something similar for subtraction.

When I write $v \cdot w$, I mean $v_x w_x + v_y w_y$; this is called the "dot product" of two vectors in the plane.

When $u = [a, b]$ is the difference between to points, i tend to write it with brackets rather than parens, as shown, and call it a "vector". When I write $u^\perp$, I mean the vector $[-b, a]$.

** To solve the two equations, it helps to rewrite one in paramteric form, as $$
X(t) = N + t w^\perp.
$$
We now want to find a value of $t$ such taht $X(t)$ lies on the other line, described by 
$$
(X - M) \cdot v = 0.
$$
So we write
\begin{align}
(N + t w^\perp - M) \cdot v &= 0 \\
(N -M + t w^\perp) \cdot v &= 0\\
(N -M) \cdot v  + t (w^\perp) \cdot v) &= 0\\
t (w^\perp) \cdot v) &= (M-N) \cdot v \\
t  &= \frac{(M-N) \cdot v}{w^\perp \cdot v)}
\end{align}
In the event that the denominator is zero, the three points are collinear and there's no solution to the problem, and it's an error.

Otherwise, we compute $t$, and plug it into 
$$
X(t) = N + t w^\perp.
$$
to get the point $Q$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I edited my post to find a simpler way, can I have your opinion about it?

Answer (score 1):

Post-edit solution.

The idea of the doubled-angle solution is great. Here's how to make it work, using the definition of the dot-product from my other answer:

Let 
$$
v = C - A \\
u = C - B
$$
Then 
$$
\theta = \cos^{-1} \frac{u \cdot v}{\sqrt{ (u \cdot u) (v \cdot v)}}
$$
is the included angle $\angle ABC$.